# How to use "Scoring Load Balancer" plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I want to run a job on different slaves, but in a predefined order.
i.e. I would like the job to run on the second machine only when all the executors of the first slave are busy.

I am trying to use "**Scoring Load Balancer**" plugin to allocate scores to different slaves,i.e. if I have 3 nodes, **NodeA,NodeB and NodeC**, having preferences of 9,5 and 1 respectively and no. of executors 10 on each node.
The nodes have a common label "WindowSlave".
Also, I have defined a job,"**ProjectX**", with project preference score of 10 and the label "**WindowSlave**" as the preferred label.

I had expected that if I run 100 concurrent builds for the "ProjectX" then the execution would happen in the order :
**NodeA(10 builds) -> NodeB(10 builds) -> NodeC(10 builds) -> NodeA(10 builds) -> NodeB(10 builds)->...** and so on.

From my observations it is still not clear if above scenario would always be achieved.
Also it happens that any random slave starts behaving as the main slave and co-ordinates with the other slave,such that all the build workspace are created on that particular slave.

What am i missing here??